# Add action-numbers in Ranorex Reports

Tags: ranorex

In Ranorex, is there a way to output the number of the action that is being executed in the test report?
By default, this is not output, but would mean a faster orientation in the error analysis.
In the corresponding report tab in the test-suite I did not find a corresponding checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ranorex support wrote me accordingly on 3/25/2023 that such a feature does not yet exist - but they will plan for it in the future. Until then, you can use the following hack:

TestSuite -> Properties -> Report -> Report template: Create custom template

Add those two snippets in RanorexReport.xsl:

1. line 645 - `<th>` with the headline: **ActionNumber (Codeline)**

   ```
            (...)
            <div class="module-container">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test=".//item">
                        <div class="module-header">
                            <xsl:call-template name="levelFilterSelector" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="module-report">
                            <TABLE border="0" cellSpacing="0" class="reporttable">
                                <thead>
                                    <th>
                                        <b>ActionNumber (Codeline)</b>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <b>Time</b>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <b>Level</b>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <b>Category</b>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <b>Message</b>
                                    </th>
                                </thead>
                                (...)
   ```
2. line 839 - `<td>` with the actionnumber and codeline itself

   ```
    (...)
    <xsl:template name="itemrow">
        <xsl:param name="tablerowclass" />
        <xsl:param name="type" />

        <tr class="{$tablerowclass}" style="{@style}" onMouseOver="DisplayHoverMenu(this)" onMouseOut="HideHoverMenu(this)">
            <td>
                <xsl:if test="metainfo/@itemindex and not(@category='Section')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./metainfo/@itemindex - count(preceding-sibling::item[@category='Section']) + 1"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="./metainfo/@codeline">
                    <xsl:text> (</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="./metainfo/@codeline"/>
                    <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </td>
            <td class="timeCell">
                <xsl:value-of select="./@time" />
            </td>
            <td class="levelCell">
                <xsl:value-of select="./@level" />
            </td>
            <td class="categoryCell">
                <xsl:value-of select="./@category" />
            </td>
            (...)
   ```

Find comparison of both xsl [here](https://www.textcompare.org/xml/?id=64551fe3b776820e17333597).

*Note: The actionnumbers for UserCode-Actions are not written into the .rxlog.data by Ranorex. They cannot be added with this xsl hack, which only manipulates the transformation of the .rxlog.data into the .rxlog.*